# Verifying that a certain collection of intervals of $\mathbb R$ forms a topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm doing exercise from "Topology without tears book", page 27, exercises a and b.

First one (a) reads as follows. "Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the set of all real numbers. Prove that each of the following collections of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is a topology.

a. $\tau_1$ consists of $\mathbb{R}$ , $\emptyset$ and every interval $(-n;n)$ for $n$ any positive integer

b. $\tau_1$ consists of $\mathbb{R}$ , $\emptyset$ and every interval $[-n;n]$ for $n$ any positive integer"

To prove this I noticied that

1. $S_n=(-n;n) \in \tau_1 \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ by definition.
2. $S_{n_1} \subset S_{n_2} \; \forall \; n_1 < n_2, n_1,\;n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$

From 2 it follows that

1. $S_{n_1} \cap S_{n_2} = S_{n_1} \; \forall n_1 < n_2 $
2. $\bigcup_{i=1}^{i=n} S_i = S_n \in S_{n+1} $

Sience intersection of any two sets is in $\tau_1$ and union of any number of sets is also in $\tau_1$ and noticing that $S_n \subset \mathbb{R} \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ I can state that $\tau_1$ is a topology of $\mathbb{R}$

Is this proven right? I have the following question. Exercise b is very similar to exercise a - the only difference is that now $[-n; n]$ is a closed interval. I think that I still can use the same prove for this case too, but not sure - does closed interval $[-n;n]$ changes anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With closure under unions, you've only shown a certain (finite) union is contained in $\tau_1$, not that an arbitrary union is (which is what the definition of a topology requires).

Let's say $U_\alpha \in \tau_1$, where $\alpha \in A$ and $A$ is some arbitrary indexing set.  Let's look at 
$$U = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A}U_\alpha$$

What can we say about $U$ if $U_\alpha = \mathbb{R}$ for some $\alpha \in A$?  What if no $U_\alpha$ is equal to $\mathbb{R}$?  (There are a couple cases: all $U_\alpha = \emptyset$, some $U_\alpha \not= \emptyset$ and the set of all $n$ such that $U_\alpha = (-n,n)$ is bounded above, and some $U_\alpha \not= \emptyset$ and the set of all $n$ such that $U_\alpha = (-n,n)$ is not bounded above).

This same method will work for $\tau_2$, as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Strants. But I'm having trouble to understand it. Can you, please, explain it in a more simplier way?

Comment: @nwnebel Well, let's take the union
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (-n,n) = \mathbb{R}$$
The set you get is bigger than any of the $S_n \in \tau_1$, but it is certainly an 'allowable' union.  You've only looked at finite unions, but you need to look at bigger, infinite unions.

Does that help?

Comment: yes, thank you, I'm following you now. I thought that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(-n,n) = \mathbb{R}$ was not possible because in the exercise it is stated that n is integer so I thought (-n,n) is a set of integers, like (-5,-4,...4,5). But now with yout help I understand that I missed the case when this interval belongs to a set of real numbers - will try to solve exercise again with this new information. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Dear @Strants, if the set of all $n$ such that $\cup_\alpha=(−n,n)$ is not bounded above then $U=\mathbb R$ immediately, right?

Comment: @rgm Correct (this is the archimedean property of the real numbers).