# Topology without tears Ex: 5 (i)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Im picking up from this question [Verifying that a certain collection of intervals of $\mathbb R$ forms a topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080096/verifying-that-a-certain-collection-of-intervals-of-mathbb-r-forms-a-topology) 
We need to prove that "Let ℝ be the set of all real numbers. Prove that each of the following collections of subsets of ℝ is a topology.

a. τ1 consists of ℝ , ∅ and every interval (−n, n) for n any positive integer

Assuming the following

$$
1)\ A_n = (-n,n) \in \tau_1, \ \forall n \in \Bbb N\\
2)\ A_n \lt A_{n+1}, \ \forall n \in \Bbb N\\
$$

Two cases for intersection and union of finite sets have already been proven in the reference above. For the infinite case i.e. When $n$ is not bounded above by [the Archimedean Property](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-archimedean-property) $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (-n, n) = \Bbb R \in \tau_1 \\$ hence proved AND We can also prove that the $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (-n, n)$ is not bounded above by [the Boundedness of Convergent Sequence Theorem](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-boundedness-of-convergent-sequences-theorem)

I've tried mailing Dr. Morris and dont have a facebook account. Can someone please tell me if I've been thinking about this correctly?

Also please let me know if the formatting of the text doesnt seem right.

Comment: What proof?  You have not shown every countable union of A's is open.  For example $\cup${ A$_{2n}$ : n in N }.

Comment: Who is Dr Morris? And why is facebook required?

Comment: @kenn  Dr. Morris is the author of Topology without tears http://topologywithouttears.net/ . I mailed him this train of thought and asked me to post it on the group forum on facebook. I've mailed him again saying that I dont have a facebook account. Hence the context.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Although I was able to prove that independently, the answer linked in the post already proves that. I figured no need to duplicate effort. Additionally the only part left open was the infinite union which is what I've tried to address here

Comment: What do you mean have you been thinking about this correctly? I can't follow your train of thought at all.

Comment: The linked question and its comments sufficiently proves that $\tau_1$ is a topology for union and intersection of finite sets. But is ambiguous for infinite sets. For the infinite case we can prove that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \ (-n, n)$ is not bounded above, hence their union is $\Bbb R$ which is in $\tau_1$ hence the union of arbitrary sets is proved which is the requirement for proving a topology. Is my train of thought correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\emptyset \ne S\subset \Bbb Z^+$ where $S$ has no largest member. Then for every $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ there exists $m\in S$ with $n<m.$ For any $r\in \Bbb R$ there exists $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ with $|r|<n$ and hence $r\in (-n,n),$ and there exists $m\in S$  with $n<m,$ so $r\in (-n,n)\subset (-m,m)\subset \cup_{m'\in S}(-m',m').$ Therefore $\Bbb R=\cup_{m'\in S}(-m',m').$

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this proves that the union of finite sets belong to $\tau_1$ which was already proven in the reference (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080096/verifying-that-a-certain-collection-of-intervals-of-mathbb-r-forms-a-topology) . Please let me know if Im missing anything.

Comment: This is about infinite $S$

Comment: if S⊂ℤ+  where S has no largest member. How does there exists m∈S and n∈ℤ+ such that n < m, shouldnt it instead be m < n ? Apologies if this sounds basic. Im just starting with topology.

Comment: Did you by any chance mean $ \Bbb Z^+ \subset \Bbb S $ ?

Comment: Because of  the definition of  $\tau 1$, if $\cup_{m\in S}(-m,m)$ belongs to $\tau 1$ for every $S\subset \Bbb Z^+,$ then $\cup T\in \tau 1$ for every $T\subset \tau 1$.  In the  case where  $S$ is not empty and has no largest member,  every $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ is less than some $m\in S.$  For example if $S=\{2^k: k\in \Bbb Z^+\}$.

Comment: I understand the properties of $ \tau1 $ I don't understand the argument about  $ S \subset \Bbb Z^+ \implies \exists m \in S \;  \land \exists n \in \Bbb Z^+ \; such \; that \; \forall n \; n \lt m$

Comment: That is not what I said. It's $\forall n\in \Bbb Z^+\,\exists m\in S \,(n<m)$ Because no $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ is an upper bound for $S$.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, it makes sense. I was caught up in the wording of the answer. Thanks a lot for your time. I was not sure if you would engage in back-forth.  I kept pushing till I "got it". Thanks again.